# How to round a double up to a given degree of precision after the decimal point?

Tags: dart, double, decimal, rounding

I need to always round the number up, with a given number of decimal places

e.g.

```
2000.301 -> 2000.31
2000.309 -> 2000.31
2000.999 -> 2001.00
2000.001 -> 2000.01

toStringAsFixed() // cant help with that


// need something like ceil(), but for decimal
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add `0.5` to a number before rounding, it will always be rounded upwards.

Applying this to two decimal places, you get:

```
(2000.301 + 0.005).toStringAsFixed(2)

=> 2000.31
```

The trick is to add as many `0`s between the decimal and the `5` as you want to have significant decimals in the output.

Cooking it into a utility function might look like:

```
import 'dart:math';

String roundToDecimals(double value, int decimals) {
  final corr = 0.5 * pow(0.1, decimals);
  return (value + corr).toStringAsFixed(decimals);
}
```

Comment: As usual with doubles, "If you add 0.5 to a number before rounding, it will always be rounded upwards." has some caveats. It only mostly works if the following rounding is `floor` (towards negative infinity). If the rounding is truncating instead (towards zero), you should add -0.5 for negative numbers.
There are still values where it doesn't do what you expect, when the `.5` is around the limits of precision of a double. Example: `var x = 9007199254740991.0; print((x + 0.5).truncate());` - which starts with an integer, so it should round back to the same number. It prints "9007199254740992".