# How do I round a number to a certain number of decimal places in Flutter (Dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example, how would I round 8.245 to 8.25 in Flutter (Dart)?
I still haven't found an effective way.
Any comments are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74786537/3525780

Answer (score 0):

In your case , you can use `toStringAsFixed`

For EX:-

```
(4321.12345678).toStringAsFixed(5);  // 4321.12346
```

For more info , go trough
https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.5/dart-core/num-class.html#id_toStringAsFixed

Comment: This rounds to the nearest integer. OP is asking rounding to two decimal places.